# Insert data from one schema to another shcema

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have two schemas in single database.

- rxdata (its a fresh schema)
- fbdata

Table name - kostst (cost center)

column name - kst_id (cost center id)

column name- kst_name (cost center name)

I would like to insert the entire data from the table `kostst` from `rxdata` to `kostst.fbdata`.
When i execute the below command, i get this and i knew that there are similar ids exists in both the schemas (kst_id=1 & 2)

```
SQL> insert into rxdata.kostst select * from fbdata.kostst;

insert into rxdata.kostst select * from fbdata.kostst
*

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (RXDATA.SYS_C0070558) violated

SQL> select table_name,column_name from user_cons_columns where constraint_name=
'SYS_C0070558';

TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME
------------  ------------
KOSTST        KST_ID
```

Comment: Could you post the DDL of your table? I am almost sure that you are violating an UNIQUE constraint on your ID column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert only the rows that don't exist, you could use:

```
insert into rxdata.kostst 
select * 
  from fbdata.kostst f
 where not exists (select null
                     from rxdata.kostst r
                    where r.kst_id = f.kst_id)
```

If you want to replace completely the table `R` by the table `F`, I suggest instead `TRUNCATE+INSERT` or `DELETE+INSERT`.